# three js full width/height without scroll

Tags: html, css

i already saw most of the answers in SO about the resizing on three js viewport, i followed mostly of them and almost archieve the final result, my issue is that i want the viewport to occupy all the window, it feels like i have a little blank space, and the scroll bar - how can i get rid of that?

[image: this is what i have at the moment:]

**the code i have is this at the moment:**

**html**

```
<div (window:resize)="onResize($event)" #container></div>
```

**ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private container : HTMLElement;

  @ViewChild('container') elementRef: ElementRef;
  private scene: THREE.Scene;
  private camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;

  private cube : THREE.Mesh;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.container = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    console.log(this.container);

    this.init();
  }

  init(){
    let screen = {
      width  : window.innerWidth,
      height : window.innerHeight
    },
    view = {
      angle  : 45,
      aspect : screen.width / screen.height,
      near   : 0.1,
      far    : 1000
    };

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(view.angle, view.aspect, view. near, view.far);
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(20));

    this.camera.position.set(10,10,10);
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

    this.renderer.setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
    this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);


    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5),
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color : 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: true });

    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    this.cube.position.set(-50,-50,-50);

    this.scene.add(this.cube);

    this.render();
  }

  render(){

    let self: AppComponent = this;

    (function render(){
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      self.renderer.render(self.scene, self.camera);

      self.animate();
    }());

  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  }

  animate(){
    this.cube.rotateX(0.1);
    this.cube.rotateY(0.1);
    this.cube.position.addScalar(0.2);

  }
}
```

Any help with this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you adjusted the CSS for `body` and/or `html` related to margin?

Comment: yeah that is fine, the problem is the scroll i want it to adjust to the full page

Comment: @costacosta As D.N. suggested, the CSS for the `<body>` tag controls the scroll bars you're seeing. Can you please share your CSS?

Comment: This question is not related to [tag:javascript] [tag:angular] [tag:three.js]

Comment: @costacosta if you remove all of the code here, you should still see an empty canvas styled with cascading style sheets (css). You need to modify these css rules to achieve the desired effect. Three.js has nothing to do with this, i assume angular very little.